# PHP import csv not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv, import

I have a problem which bothers me for the past few days. I searched and tried everything, but till now, nothing worked.

In short: I have a csv upload which is working fine, but the data import itself is not working.

This is the full script (security is no issue since only certain people can acces this anyway, but feel free to add suggestions for it):

```
if(isset($_POST['athene_advanced_submit_csv'])){
$admin_valid = true; //not doing anything yet

if($admin_valid == true){
    $filename = $_FILES['athene_files']['name'];
    $target_path = '../db/';
    $result_files = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['athene_files']['tmp_name'], $target_path.$filename);


    if($result_files == true){
        $query_import = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'import.csv'
        INTO TABLE `test`
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\r\n'
        (id, name, price)";

        $result_import = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query_import);

        if($result_import == true){
            echo '<script>alert("CSV imported");</script>';     
        }else{
            echo '<script>alert("import error");</script>';     
        }
    }else{
        echo '<script>alert("file error");</script>';   
    }

}
else{
    echo '<script>alert("no file");</script>';  
}
```

}

It returns "Import error" over and over.

my csv is as following:

```
id,name,price
1,one,12
2,two,23
3,three,34
4,four,45
5,five,56
6,six,67
7,seven,78
```

Can somebody help me? I think the problem is that my query is not suitable for the export of my csv, but haven't found a solution yet.

Very many thanks in advance!

Comment: `LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\r\n'` Why the commas?

Comment: use `mysqli_error` to get the reason

Comment: To be honest, It worked in an example here on Stackoverflow. I changed the commas with \n (since my csv only uses lines) but still did not work. Thought it would be better to just show this instead.

Comment: it's your path (or lack thereof) plus all that extra comma jazz once it finds it

Comment: @Drew I hoped you were right, but changing the path in the query to ../db/import.csv did not work unfortunaly. Still, i believe that is one of the factors as well, so i changed it.

Comment: I would absolute path it not relative. Stick it in a folder off the root. What OS are you using. You have too many unknowns here. Remove a few

Comment: if you had PHP error reporting setup fine PHP would choke on it and show an error

Comment: PHP error reporting shows nothing (empty). the OS is windows. Servers on windows if i am not mistaken. Then again, this is new for me, and i am not sure how to handle this, since I am learning :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/your/absolute/path/import.csv' INTO TABLE `test`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  ## if windows '\r\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (id, name, price)";
```

Comment: Sorry, I just saw your message! Open mysql and type: SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';  If it says that are OFF set it ON by: SET GLOBAL local_infile = 'ON';  Then check again!

Comment: If still not working you can use before run your query: $dbcon->mysqli_init(); $dbcon->options(MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INIFILE, true);

Comment: no problem! i will try it tomorrow, and will try it out!